# Hyperledger - database index

Tags: indexing, hyperledger, rocksdb, hyperledger-fabric

I'm new to hyperledger and was wondering where I could find documentation related to how the database in hyperledger works.

By looking at difference examples, it seems that it is a simple key,value storage. However, I'm currently working on a POC where we'll need to store documents into hyperledger, which means that we should be able to index them in order to query and retrieve the needed data.

Are there some libraries which allow to index documents( similar to lucene/elasticsearch) into hyperledger database?

Answer (score 4):

Fabric v1.0 has a key/value data model, as well as a document data model option based on CouchDB. When using CouchDB with JSON data you can query individual fields within your data content from chaincode.

Even with the key/value data model, you can model your own 'index' in chaincode as a key to resolve your queries.

See the Fabric v1.0 marbles02 chaincode example which demonstrates both data patterns:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/examples/chaincode/go/marbles02/marbles_chaincode.go

Answer (score 1):

Key-value store in Fabric backed by RocksDB. You can try to use libraries which work with this database.

Keep in mind that Hyperledger is designed for privacy. In production environment with `security.privacy: true` the documents will be encrypted and indexing will not be possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Regarding RockdDB, i m trying to find a library but I can't... most importantly, the documents that will be stored are "common knowledge" so need to encrypt them. Is it possible in hyperledger to define which data to encrypt in production ?

Comment: Right now there is no granular control on "which data to encrypt", it possible that this functional will be implemented later. Getting back to the original question - In fabric v1 in "core.yaml" there is a configuration parameter "stateDatabase". It can be easier for you to work with CouchDB for db indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to manage file is to store a hash of the file in the blockchain and the authorized entity will be able to verify that the file is valid or not. You could use IPFS or Google Drive or any other mechanism to share the data as long as the access control mechanism is implemented properly.